# Не работает htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Не могу настроить htaccess в Apache 2.4.7. Создал проект, главная страница отдается, все нормально, все файлы, которые лежат в корне сайта, отдаются отлично. Но как только перехожу по ссылке ЧПУ, то сразу пишет, что такого файла не существует. Как можно это поправить?

Comment: mod_rewrite установлен? (`apachectl -M | grep rewrite`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_rewrite - ага, он установлен, все, нашел ошибку... при создании хоста не указал одну строчку, которая оказалась критичной:

```
<Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```