# Сервер не видит .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, debian, веб-сервер

Купил vps, установил apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin и перед этим обновил пакеты (Сервер настраиваю впервые).

Залил сайт, подключил бд, все работает. Но не видит вообще файла .htaccess.

Поставил на него права 777, ничего не изменилось.

Строки

`<Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
</Directory>`

тоже не помогли (Писал это в файл apache2.conf)

OC Debian 7.4, 64 bit.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает htaccess](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/362642/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-htaccess)

Comment: речь о директиве allowoverride.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в файле `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` пропиши вот это:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

`/var/www/` - это твоя директория, где лежит проект

Answer (score 0):

**Может быть у вас не включён `rewrite` ?**

---

Попробуйте:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

После этого перезагрузите Apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Возможно, кому-то я помог.

#apache2 #htaccess #vps